# Android studio build error- RN expo eject expoKit

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio, expo

At Android Studio after expo eject to expoKit I've got error during the building:

Error

```
:app:pprocessDebugGoogleServices

org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to delete: project_dir\android\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug

at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask.deleteFolder(GoogleServicesTask.java:501)

at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask.action(GoogleServicesTask.java:95)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

at java.lang.Thread.run
```

App ejected by `expo eject` -> ExpoKit

Windows 10, Android Studio 3.5, expoSdk 34.0.0

cleaning project doesn't work,
same error on new project made by `expo init`

Comment: Try to run Android studio as administrator